# Are "pity" and "contempt" compatible sentiments?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

The Mayor of Rio is reported as saying that he had both *pity* and *contempt* for the US athletes who made a false report to police about having been robbed, after they had committed an act of vandalism.

Are *pity* and *contempt* compatible? Can one have genuine *pity* for someone one holds in contempt?

Comment: I can see what you're getting at.  I agree with your implication that the mix is somewhat impossible.  Note that there **are** really slap-down combos like that: the speaker (who is not even a native English speaker) was IMO trying to reach for one of those combos.  Don't you agree?

Comment: Wait - was the quote not in English?  In that case, translations are irrelevant.

Comment: This has just resurfaced. Miller distinguishes contempt and disgust, but the dictionaries I've checked in don't seem to make that distinction at default-sense level. So the answer giving his opinion must be considered unconvincing (he says disgust precludes pity). Certainly horror (which need not mean despising; horror at a natural disaster say) and pity aren't irreconcilable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to William Ian Miller in "[The Anatomy of Disgust](https://books.google.es/books?id=Sob-yhXKLhIC&pg=PA32&lpg=PA32&dq=%22pity%20and%20contempt%22%20-rio%20-mayor&source=bl&ots=kZhL8VF9NF&sig=4619vPX1DfbaEWupVh38Drd3gso&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj9gtaHns7OAhVRahoKHdG8AGkQ6AEIRTAH#v=onepage&q=%22pity%20and%20contempt%22%20-rio%20-mayor&f=false)",

```
Pity and contempt go hand in hand
```

So he'd say they're more than just compatible. (And so would Nietzsche.)

Comment: What an extraordinarily apt reply! The question should perhaps have been asked on a Philosopy, or Psychology site. But you have done justice to it. I wonder if the Mayor realises he is a Millerian? And I wonder if it comes out the same in Portuguese?

Comment: Apparently he says "Meu único sentimento por eles é de pena e desprezo", which I think is quite close to pity and contempt: he feels sorry for their sad performance.

Comment: I wanted to say that this answer is pitiful and contemptible, but I can't. So I upvoted it.

Comment: If it's a translation the whole issue is a time-waste.  I would translate it more like "I am torn between pity and contempt..." (or "I go back and fore between..."). That combo can't exist, as the question implies.

Comment: @JoeBlow Well, he is Professor of Law at the University of Michigan and has an extraordinarily impressive academic CV in law, history and philosophy. So my guess is that his remarks can not entirely be dismissed.

Answer (score -1):

Imo pity is not compatible with contempt.  And for those using the word pity (compossionate sympothetic sorrow for anothers suffering)  contemptuously i consider them arrogant, sarcastic and mean. Obtw, I do not pity the arrogant or the mean, i do feel sorrow for their  foolishness and lack of humility; and not sympathetic to any suffering, only their foolishness. In this case both parties (include the mayor) are not to be pitied as bith were arrogant and foolish.